# cassandra node not starting

Tags: cassandra, nullpointerexception

I have 4 node cassandra cluster. out of which 2 are up but 2 are down. 
when I start them they immediately getting down.
when I check using `service cassandra status`
I am getting `could not access pidfile for cassandra`
and in system.log file, the error is:

```
ERROR [main] 2017-09-15 15:44:46,277 CassandraDaemon.java:752 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.isSafeForStartup(Gossiper.java:756) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:553) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:800) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:666) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:612) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:394) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:735) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-09-15 15:44:46,281 HintsService.java:221 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-09-15 15:44:46,282 Gossiper.java:1506 - Announcing shutdown
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: the version is 3.10

Comment: Can you please execute a `bin/nodetool status` command on any running node and paste the result? Also highlight the node that threw the NullPointerException above.

Comment: Also what would be useful for troubleshooting is executing `bin/nodetool gossipinfo` and pasting the results here.

Answer (score 0):

From source code of `Gossiper`([link](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/legacy/apache-cassandra-3.10-src.tar.gz/apache-cassandra-3.10-src/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/gms/Gossiper.java)), I suspect that your nodes are stuck in **boostrapping** phase. Other nodes see them as already bootstrapped, but they failed to finish joining the cluster.

What could help is forcibly removing stuck nodes from your cluster, by using `nodetool removenode` in any other instance that was able to boot.
After that, you should clean data on the stuck instances by wiping out `data`directory (located in `data/` or under [system folder](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/latest/cassandra/initialize/referenceClearCpkgData.html), if you installed from OS package) and start instances one-by-one.

If you send the **gossipinfo** and **status** of your cluster, it might help to figure out what the real problem is.

For further reference [see official guide](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/latest/cassandra/operations/opsAddNodeToCluster.html)

Comment: Thanks Oresztesz. I did the same thing but not used removenode option. Instead I removed the seeds from the cassandra.yaml file and then restarted cassandra to check whether it is running properly out of cluster. and it was running fine. then I added the seeds back to cassandra.yaml file. and restarted the cassandra then it works in cluster as well. One thing I saw in system.log is that there is a log that `updating topology information for that node`. I am still not getting clearly what was the problem but it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

One cause can be misconfigured ip addresses/seeds:

Double-check the cluster name, the seeds are the same on all nodes in their cassandra.yaml file and that all of the ip addresses are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In `cassandra.yaml` file , comment these values and let it use default

```
data_file_directories: db/cassandra/data

commitlog_directory: db/cassandra/commitlog
```